# How to configure php to upload more than 2gb file

Tags: php

Read many posts and finally came to this solution
I need to edit the php code and compile it by hand (make sure to compile it as 64-bit). here’s a link to a list of diffs:

http://www.neanderthal-technology.com/code/2gblimit/karmic-64bit-post-large-files.patch

git:
https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/372/files

how to do this?

I do not want to use FTP. I want php to upload my files to my local server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a source patch. You need the PHP source code, apply the patch and then compile the code. However I don't think this is necessary. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425608/3850993

Comment: Done as it says with 3G upload and post max size in php.ini.
Restarted the server and wordpress came up with this error
File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

Comment: Is this your own server?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to recustomize php.ini

```
post_max_size = 2G
upload_max_filesize = 2G
```

And still it is necessary to change parameter "memory_limit" that the server could digest the file

Comment: And if to establish slightly bigger value? After all there with post inquiry still data are transferred and goes not 2gb, and it is slightly more. 
Besides the hoster can block big parameters.

Comment: Now files are correctly uploading but not more than 2gb, I have tried many ways modifying .htaccess php.ini but nothing is working... !!