# Increase upload size in your php

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload videos up to 2 GB therefore, I changed the php ini file:

`memory_limit = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
post_max_size = 2048M`

but I couldn't upload more than 1 MB, ***Why is that?***

I know its a common question but I tried so many solutions and it didn't workout.

***Software Specifications***

– Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64 – Apache 2.4.23 – PHP 5.6.25/7.0.10 – MySQL 5.7.14

– PhpMyAdmin 4.6.4 – Adminer 4.2.5 – PhpSysInfo 3.2.5

Comment: This might have something more to do with your hardware than your software.

Comment: Are you able to upload any file ?

Comment: This is a source patch. You need the PHP source code, apply the patch and then compile the code. However, I don't think this is necessary. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425608/3850993

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to check the following:

```
max_input_time -1 (unlimited)

file_uploads = On

mysql.connect_timeout = 360 (1 hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit both the php.ini files. You can find it here:

1)`wamp/bin/php/php x.x.x/php.ini`
 2)`wamp/bin/apache/apache x.x.x/bin/php.ini`

and I prefer increasing the memory_limit , upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in both the files.

Thank you.